# Adapt print function formatting to skip missing values

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am looking to have a standard python function where if it doesn't see the title/value then it just skips that and prints the rest.

In other words, let's suppose I have three values `Job` , `Dept` and `Designation`, and if the `Job` is missing then skip that and print the other two.

Is there a way in python or python3 to do the job?

Here's an example:

```
>>> print("Job: %s\nDept: %s\nDesignation: %s" %('cad', 'tl', 'it'))
Job: cad
Dept: tl
Designation: it
```

Comment: How are you supposed to know which value is missing?

Comment: How do you get your input?

Comment: @chrisz , we are extracting the data from this format right so, sometimes these values are missing as per the data patterns we analysed.

Comment: @zipa indeed we are extarcting the data directly from Elasticsearch RESTful search and analytics engine by modeling the filers while importing the Elasticsearch  itself as its a database as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way. It assumes a value is "missing" if it is not `True`, e.g. 0, `False`, empty string, `None`.

```
def printer(cat, val):
    for i, j in zip(cat, val):
        if j:
            print('{0}: {1}'.format(i, j))

cats = ['Job', 'Dept', 'Designation']

printer(cats, ['cad', 'tl', 'it'])
# Job: cad
# Dept: tl
# Designation: it

printer(cats, ['cad', '', 'it'])
# Job: cad
# Designation: it
```